# How do I tell summary to not wrap columns?

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to get summary to not wrap its output. However, when I call summary with 5 columns of data, it places the 5th column on a separate row. I am hoping there is a way that's easier than manually printing iterating over the object returned by summary.

Best Regards,

Joseph

plotit.r

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
noneData <- read.csv("query.log", header=FALSE, sep="\t");
cnames = c( 'vids', 'partitions', 'localvert', 'remotevert',
                    'cachehits', 'responsetime' );
colnames(noneData) <- cnames;
cachenames = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
responseCompare = data.frame(
   noneData$responsetime/1000000,
   noneData$responsetime/1000000,
   noneData$responsetime/1000000,
   noneData$responsetime/1000000,
   noneData$responsetime/1000000
   );
colnames(responseCompare) <- cachenames;
print("Response Times");
summary(responseCompare);
```

./plotit.r #output:

```
[1] "Response Times"
       1                  2                  3                  4         
 Min.   :   0.215   Min.   :   0.215   Min.   :   0.215   Min.   :   0.215
 1st Qu.: 395.202   1st Qu.: 395.202   1st Qu.: 395.202   1st Qu.: 395.202
 Median : 459.888   Median : 459.888   Median : 459.888   Median : 459.888
 Mean   : 466.726   Mean   : 466.726   Mean   : 466.726   Mean   : 466.726
 3rd Qu.: 530.122   3rd Qu.: 530.122   3rd Qu.: 530.122   3rd Qu.: 530.122
 Max.   :3275.916   Max.   :3275.916   Max.   :3275.916   Max.   :3275.916
       5          
 Min.   :   0.215 
 1st Qu.: 395.202 
 Median : 459.888 
 Mean   : 466.726 
 3rd Qu.: 530.122 
 Max.   :3275.916
```

Comment: `options(width=120) ; cat("Response Times"); summary(responseCompare)`

Comment: `summary` is not wrapping your columns, Terminal/ your gui is.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta : my terminal/gui is not wrapping the columns. Firstly, my terminal is sufficiently large to display all columns. Secondly, the problem is repeated if I output to a file (./plotit.r > file.txt )

Comment: @Dwin: That solved the problem. Why did you comment instead of leaving answer as I cannot 'accept' a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `options()` function gives you a method of creating side-effects in the R console environment:

```
 names( options() )
 options(width=120) ; cat("Response Times"); summary(responseCompare)
```

The print method will then only add "\n" when it reaches a "virtual end of page" at 120 total characters. It calculates the width of columns and only prints a batch of columns at a time.

Comment: ...so set a large number to turn line wrapping "off"