# How to control R's default printing of dataframe columns to console

Tags: r, cmd, dataframe, pretty-print, rscript

I'm working on an R script that will print out duplicated observations to the console for a data frame snippet that I tease out using only the relevant ID columns I need to pinpoint the observations. I was surprised to find the last two columns printed within a separate block rather than appended to the right. I'm invoking the script via RScript.exe in a Windows7 command shell so maybe there's some interplay there I need to wrangle down?

```
* ERROR--duplicated observations present in DataFrame xxx:

                                       Column1   Column2   Column3
11830   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       123       193
11831   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       123       193
11834   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       121       196
11837   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       124       197
11839   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       150       186
11842   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       190       167
11853  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       101         0
11858  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       143       147
11871  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       178       163
11876  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       166       174
12093  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       173       222
12117  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       153       199
12186  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       113       205
12198  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       150       226
12285  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       178       176
12298 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       166       170
            Column4       Column5
11830           206           292
11831           206           292
11834           302           324
11837           220           313
11839           271           303
11842           326           293
11853           220           377
11858           281           296
11871           354           348
11876           305           337
12093           291           369
12117           248           309
12186           276           342
12198           247           321
12285           321           320
12298           291           281
```

I'm really just expected something to be printed more inline with what I've tabulated below. This column breaking behavior doesn't really show up in RGUI as the max screen width seems to stretch the contents horizontally as much as possible before breaking

```
                                       Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5
11830   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       123       193       206       292
11831   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       123       193       206       292
11834   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       121       196       302       324
11837   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       124       197       220       313
11839   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       150       186       271       303
11842   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       190       167       326       293
11853  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       101         0       220       377
11858  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       143       147       281       296
11871  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       178       163       354       348
11876  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       166       174       305       337
12093  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       173       222       291       369
12117  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       153       199       248       309
12186  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       113       205       276       342
12198  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       150       226       247       321
12285  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       178       176       321       320
12298 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       166       170       291       281
```

Comment: `options("width"=120)`  See `?options`

Comment: @BondedDust, aha just realized this may be a near duplicate of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506792/how-do-i-tell-summary-to-not-wrap-columns?rq=1). This could definitely explain it since the default is a mere 80 characters, which is close to the 66 characters in line 12298.

Comment: @BondedDust I haven't had a chance to test the options setting out yet but the odd thing is that earlier in the script output there's a line printed that has 201 characters and is not broken. It's basically the full path to a CSV file that's being printed. I'm not sure I can explain this discrepancy in breaking behavior.

Comment: Printing character valued items is different than printing column values that are part of dataframes.

Comment: So I just tested width out this morning and it resolved the problem. I'm trying to understand the nature of the difference in printing behavior and see the options documentation says

_width: controls the maximum number of columns on a line **used in printing vectors, matrices and arrays**, and when filling by cat._

Comment: Then I realized breaking a really long string into sections is more straightforward to continue reading onto the next line than breaking text in the middle of an element of an array where for all you know may be two distinct elements. Communicating continuation with mid element breaks would be a horrible idea and information would be lost. So now I realize clearly vector element entities need to print their elements in their entirety, so you gotta break somewhere, and upon a full column, and R called the default at 80 chars. Fair enough.