# shinydashboard not using full width of box()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Having a slight issue with my box in the main body of my shinyApp. For some reason when I brush a section of the graph it doesn't use the full width of the box to display the data. Any clue what I'm missing to get this to output a little cleaner?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(MASS)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Clicking"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("CerealPlot",
                 brush = "brushing"),
      box((verbatimTextOutput("coords")), width = 12)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$CerealPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = UScereal$protein, y = UScereal$calories,
         xlab = "Protein (gm)",
         ylab = "Calories",
         pch = as.character(UScereal$mfr))
  })
  
  output$coords <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(UScereal, input$brushing, xvar = "protein",
               yvar = "calories")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is an image of what I'm seeing in case there are troubles reproducing.

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  That is, I get all data in two rows in the above brushed selection.

Comment: @YBS I see the same behavior as OP when highlighting data points with an extra long rowname, like "Fruit & Fibre: Dates Walnuts and Oats"

Answer (score 0):

Your `verbatimTextOutput` is basically displaying what you would otherwise see if you printed those results to your R console. It's similar to this question: [How do I tell summary to not wrap columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506792/how-do-i-tell-summary-to-not-wrap-columns).

**Simple solution** is to add `options(width=120)` to your app - this will give you the behavior you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could consider using `renderTable` + `tableOutput` or `renderDataTable` + `dataTableOutput` - [lots of cool customization options](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html).

Code below. I left the other two options commented out if you want to see what they look like.

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(MASS)

options(width=120)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Clicking"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("CerealPlot",
                 brush = "brushing"),
      box(verbatimTextOutput("coords"), width = 12) # option a: original question
      #box(tableOutput("coords"), width = 12)       # option b: generic table
      #box(dataTableOutput("coords"), width = 12)   # option c: fancy data table
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$CerealPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = UScereal$protein, y = UScereal$calories,
         xlab = "Protein (gm)",
         ylab = "Calories",
         pch = as.character(UScereal$mfr))
  })

  output$coords <- renderPrint({       # option a: original question
  #output$coords <- renderTable({      # option b: generic table
  #output$coords <- renderDataTable({  # option c: fancy data table

    brushedPoints(UScereal
                  , input$brushing
                  , xvar = "protein"
                  , yvar = "calories")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```